# Comparing AX register against zero

Tags: x86-16, assembly

I have a assembly program to write. I need to check the AX register, if the AX register is greater than 0 move +1 in BX, if the AX register has a value less than 0 then move -1 in BX else if AX =0 then move 0 in BX. I have the following code that does it but I am looking for an alternate solution. Please help out. Thanks

```
CMP AX, 0
JG GREATER
JL LESS
MOV BX, 0
GREATER:
MOV BX, 1
LESS:
MOV BX, -1
```

Comment: Why do you need an alternate solution?

Comment: @KendallFrey: I want to understand if there is another way around to do it.

Comment: You can do it any way you want. If you want, build your own hardware device to do the conversion. In other words, there are many ways to do it. Just use a small solution that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you gave always returns -1. Try this:

```
CMP AX, 0
JG GREATER
JL LESS
MOV BX, 0
JMP END
GREATER:
MOV BX, 1
JMP END
LESS:
MOV BX, -1
END:
```

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thanks for adding the terminating jump to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which only requires a single conditional branch and no unconditional jumps:

```
    mov     bx, ax      // copy ax to bx
    sarw    bx, 15      // arithmetic shift - any -ve => -1, 0 or +ve => 0
    cmp     ax, 0       // compare original number to zero
    jle     end         // if it's <=, we're done
    mov     bx, 1       // else bx = 1
end:
```

**NB** - my x86 code is *very very* rusty.  Also, that version of `sar` wasn't in the 8086, but was in the 286 and later, and didn't get particularly speedy until the 80386.

**EDIT** I think I found a better version for 386+ without any branches:

```
    mov     bx, ax     // copy ax to bx      
    sarw    bx, 15     // arithmetic shift - any -ve => -1, 0 or +ve => 0
    cmp     ax, 0      // compare original to zero
    setg    bl         // if it was greater, bl = 1 (bh already == 0 from above)
```